# Phusion passenger and running multiple ruby version with apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have two different rails websites buid on ruby 1.8.x and ruby 1.9.11 respectively. I already have configured my /etc/httpd/conf/http.conf with the following lines of code:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.18/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.18
PassengerRuby /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby
```

as suggested by
    **passenger-install-apache2-module**

likewise I have also added the further necessary code replacing the substitutes :

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>       ServerName www.example.com
>       # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
>       DocumentRoot /somewhere/public    
>       <Directory /somewhere/public>
>          # This relaxes Apache security settings.
>          AllowOverride all
>          # MultiViews must be turned off.
>          Options -MultiViews
>       </Directory>   
>  </VirtualHost>
> ```

All works fine, till now but when I try to add another configuration for ruby 1.9.3 app, and follow the above same process, then I am not able to run both ruby 1.8.7 app and 1.9.3 app simultaneously.The latter runs successfully where as the former generates error.

I am using rvm to manage both apps, and have seperate gemsets for each of the application.

So, my question is that, **how can I run both my applications simultaneously.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run multiple ruby version simultaneously within a single phussion passenger configuration. If this is the case then one should run with the standalone server (let's say on port 4000) and the you should configure apache to run as a proxy on that port. See http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/ for more information.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. Check the next one.

Answer (score 8):

Passenger 4 allows `PassengerRuby` to be set per application.

- http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/03/05/phusion-passenger-4-0-release-candidate-4/

The final release is just around the corner but in the mean time you can install it via `gem install passenger --pre`.

Comment: hm, that's nice to know